# Should we add DIY to the off-topic close reasons?

Tags: feature-request

As this is [not the first ime](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94196/cast-iron-skillet-with-lid-rusted-togethe) this week that I see a question that would be more suited to [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) than here, could we please add that site to our off-topic close reasons:

[image: Close Reasons Screenshot]

as there seems to be a lot of space left on that screen anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, the number of questions that were migrated (away) this year is twelve. Of those, more than half went to Coffee SE, partly because we have a [bilateral migration agreement](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/migrating-questions-to-and-from-coffee-stackexchange-com). 
Less than ten percent of all successfully migrated posts ever went to Home Improvement.

Considering that, a moderator flag with a short explanation should suffice.

Comment: Thank you! **:-)**